# App crashing at CLLocationCoordinate2DMake - swift

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit, core-location

here's my getMapAnnotations() function that is supposed to get latitude and longitude information from a firebase database and add those annotations to the mapView:

```
func getMapAnnotations()  {
    print("aa")
    var refHandle = self.ref.child("tasks").observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let tasksDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        print("bb")
        for i in 0 ..< tasksDict!.count {
                let taskId = tasksDict!.allKeys[i] as! String
                print (taskId)
                let task = tasksDict!.objectForKey(taskId) as! NSDictionary
                print (task)
                let lat = task.objectForKey("latitude") as! String
                let long = task.objectForKey("longitude") as! String
                let latNum = Double(lat)
                let longNum = Double(long)
                let latDegrees: CLLocationDegrees = latNum!
                let longDegrees: CLLocationDegrees = longNum!
                let pointLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latDegrees, longDegrees)
                let point = MKPointAnnotation()
                point.coordinate = pointLocation
                point.title = task.objectForKey("title") as? String
                self.homeMap.addAnnotation(point)
                print("point added")

        }
```

The app becomes unresponsive when the view controller loads and the breakpoint is at the pointLocation declaration. Is there something I'm not doing right here? Thanks.

Comment: First most obvious thing to check, what values do latDegrees and longDegrees have.

Comment: @SausageModulationMatrix they are the correct coordinates for the pin I want to show, in this case 37.3323314 and 122.0312186

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with that specific line if the values are ok. Does the loop only execute once?

Comment: @SausageModulationMatrix There are currently two points in the database so it should theoretically run twice. But it doesn't even get to the line where it prints "point added" so I know it's getting stuck before then. I tried moving the point = MKPointAnnotation() declaration as an instance variable but the same thing happened. It appears to crash at this point every time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a breakpoint set up at that line. Oh man that's embarrassing.